# Can't get keydown event to fire on specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to get the `keydown` event to fire whenever the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key is pressed while in a certain context of my web application. For example, I have an online file system implemented, and when that view is in use, I want the `keydown` event to be active.

However, I also have certain popups that come up over the page when certain actions are performed. When these popups are visible, I'd like the `keydown` event to be disabled, because that event interferes with their functionality. The working event code that I have currently doesn't do this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event){
   if(event.which === 46 && ($('.selected').size() > 0)){
       saveDelete();
   }
});
```

Is there a way to have this `keydown` event stop firing under certain conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want .length (no parenthesis) rather than .size() ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your code to use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) instead of size.
2. When you popup is visible you can unbind the event handler by calling [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and when your popup is not visible or user closes it you can again reattach the keyevent by calling [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), this will work if you are using jQuery 1.7 for earlier releases you will have to use [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [`.unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but try this-

```
window.onkeydown(function(){
//code goes here
});
```